# missing publish output after ASP.NET MVC 5 to Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web upgrade

Tags: c#, asp.net

I try to migrate a `ASP.NET MVC 5` (`349C5851-65DF-11DA-9384-00065B846F21`) project to `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web` structure.

My project file after conversion looks like:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
    <TargetFramework>net48</TargetFramework>
    <OutputPath>$(SolutionDir)bin\ptc\$(Configuration)\</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
    <OptionStrict>On</OptionStrict>
    <GenerateAssemblyInfo>false</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
</Project>
...
```

It has the publish option on context menu. But if I publish it the output has a difference to the old format:

#### Project Source: (`clean state`)

```
C:.
├───BusinessObjects
├───Images
├───My Project
│   ├───MyExtensions
│   └───PublishProfiles
├───Scripts
│   └───lib
└───Shared
```

#### Publish Old: (`C:\publish\old`)

```
C:.
├───bin (binary files are here)
│   └───roslyn
├───Images
├───Scripts
│   └───lib
├───Shared
└──(*.aspx and *.htm)
```

#### Publish New: (`C:\publish\new`)

```
C:.
├──refs
└──(binary files are here, no *.aspx, no *.htm)
```

---

I do not understand the complete publish mechanism behind this process. What have I add to my new format that have the publish same output like before?

Comment: Publishing folders aren't named like that nor do they appear inside `Debug`. What you posted are *temporary* folders used during the packaging process, not the actual published files. You shouldn't be using them directly. How did you publish the project until now?

Comment: You are totally correct. I fixed the folder output and set the `target location` to capture the _actual published files_ (`publish -> new -> folder`). But the result is the same.